# can not listen on Window object node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I watched [this vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vodSlnuwy18&index=2&list=PLkyEadCJGLm0-yn8wi-a5n8H7lKll23t9).In this vedio,`window.on('maximize')` is used when 'Window' is minimized or maximized,in order to get correct minimize state of `Window`,but I could not get any response trough the listener  when I maximize the `Window`.And I pasted the code,it also did not work,`-` is minimize,`o`is maximize,`x`is close.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Turbo</title>
        <script>

            var nw = require('nw.gui');
            var win = nw.Window.get();
            win.isMaximized = false;

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#' title='Minimize' id='windowControlMinimize'>-</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href='#' title='Maximize' id='windowControlMaximize'>o</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href='#' title='Close'    id='windowControlClose'   >x</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <script>

        // Min
        document.getElementById('windowControlMinimize').onclick = function()
        {
            win.minimize();
        };

        // Close
        document.getElementById('windowControlClose').onclick = function()
        {
            win.close();
        };

        // Max
        document.getElementById('windowControlMaximize').onclick = function()
        {
            if (win.isMaximized)
                win.unmaximize();
            else
                win.maximize();
        };

        // Listen to the minimize event
        win.on('minimize', function() {
              console.log('Window is minimized');
        });

        win.on('maximize', function(){
            win.isMaximized = true;
        });

        win.on('unmaximize', function(){
            win.isMaximized = false;
        });


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what errors are you running into ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla when I clicked `o`,`win.isMaximized = true` would not run.

Comment: I also got some errors about linux sandbox,but I think it does not matter.

Comment: that's weird, I copy pasted your code and it works perfectly for me. Which version of node-webkit are you using?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla I am using v0.11.1-linux-x64 node-webkit and I node is v0.10.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because I am using node-v0.10.33,it is only compatible with node-webkit v0.8